# Problem attaching multiple NICs to a VM in Azure using a Terraform module

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

We are developing a module to create Linux based NVAs. Each NVA needs to have 3 NICs attached to it, each on a different subnet. At the moment, the module is able to successfully create the 3 NICs but the output from the NIC creation is of type `tuple` and we have not figured out how to use the NIC Resource IDs stored in the `tuple` as input into the VM creation.

We are trying to keep the module generic enough to be able to use it to create other types of Linux VMs that may not have multiple NICs.

Working code that calls module to create the NICs:

```
module "linux_vm" {
  source              = "../modules/test_module"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.saca_rg.name
  nic_names           = ["nic-mgmt","nic-int","nic-ext"]
  subnet_id           = ["${local.subnet_ids[4]}","${local.subnet_ids[3]}","${local.subnet_ids[2]}"]
  ip_allocation       = ["Static","Static","Static"]
  static_ip           = ["${cidrhost(local.static_ips[4], 4)}","${cidrhost(local.static_ips[3], 4)}","${cidrhost(local.static_ips[2], 4)}"]
}
```

Module code that creates the NICs:

```
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "vm_nic" {
  count               = length(var.nic_names)
  name                = var.nic_names[count.index]
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.location

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "${var.nic_names[count.index]}-ipconfig"
    subnet_id                     = var.subnet_id[count.index]
    private_ip_address_allocation = var.ip_allocation[count.index]
    private_ip_address            = var.static_ip[count.index]
  }
}
```

The output from this is a `tuple` that resembles the output below:

```
"outputs": {
    "nic_ids": {
      "value": [
        "/subscriptions/<sub_id>/resourceGroups/rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/nic-mgmt",
        "/subscriptions/<sub_id>/resourceGroups/rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/nic-int",
        "/subscriptions/<sub_id>/resourceGroups/rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/nic-ext"
      ],
      "type": [
        "tuple",
        [
          "string",
          "string",
          "string"
        ]
      ]
    }
  },
```

When we try to use this output as input into the VM creation block using the parameter below:

```
network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.vm_nic.*.id]
```

We get the error generated below:

```
Error: Incorrect attribute value type

  on ../modules/test_module/main.tf line 27, in resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "vm":
  27:   network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.vm_nic.*.id]
    |----------------
    | azurerm_network_interface.vm_nic is tuple with 3 elements

Inappropriate value for attribute "network_interface_ids": element 0: string
required.
```

Answer (score 1):

Discovered what the problem was.

We were trying to use the line below:

```
network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.vm_nic.*.id]
```

But since a `tuple` is like a list...this was basically nesting a list inside of a list. When we switched to the below, all 3 NICs assigned as expected:

```
network_interface_ids = azurerm_network_interface.vm_nic.*.id
```

Comment: I am trying the scenario. But the concern here is number of NIC attached to the VM depends on the size of VM, I have to handle this check as well. How did you handle this validation. Any idea from you side would be much appreciated.